# Fancybox with IE9 redirect to ajax action

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento, internet-explorer-9, fancybox

I'm trying to use Fancybox with magento admin, all working fine except for IE9 exists what happen:
I'm feeding my fancybox by ajax, my link is like this:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="http://10.1.1.34/clovis/index.php/ClearSale/Standard/Index/codPedidoCS/100000048/">ClearSale</a>
```

My fancybox calls:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function() {
             jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox();
        });
</script>
```

My ajax return:

```
echo "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\"><b><span style='color:red;'>Ocorreu um erro, por favor entre em contato com o suporte.</span></b>";
```

But this ajax return could be anything and i have the same issue.
What happens: On firefox all work fine. but on IE9 when i click on link he show the fancybox for 2 seconds, and redirect to one page with the ajax return.i've tryed all, and nothing work, i've opend the Demo file of fancybox and on ajax example happen the same behavior, but show the message on browser "Active the activeX" and if i active all works fine, but on my code don't ask to active the activeX. I don't no what more i can do. 
Someone help's pls.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, i don't know who or why, but when i tell:

```
<a href="www.google.com"/>
```

And take the a click with jquery and use prevent return false or preventDefault to dont send to url IE9 get crazy and can't do that. So, when i tell href='php action reference' fancybox try load the return on the fancybox and prevent url to load. But this isn't happens  on ie9, he opened the box and make the redirect.
So my solution is, i make a div on my .phtml to use to load the content. And do that:

```
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.fancybox').bind('click',function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                  url: jQuery(this).attr('href'),
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(html){
                      jQuery('#clearsale').html(html);
                  }
                });
            jQuery.fancybox(jQuery('#clearsale'));
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>   
<div id="clearsale" style="width:600px;height:100px;display: none;">
</div>
```

Now work's fine.